# Firebase login throws Error: spawn cmd ENOENT in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-cli

I am trying to set up my Firebase TypeScript application on another system. When I execute `firebase login`, it throws the following exception:

```
[debug] [2020-07-10T12:35:28.031Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2020-07-10T12:35:28.034Z] Command:       C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\gp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js login
[debug] [2020-07-10T12:35:28.034Z] CLI Version:   8.5.0
[debug] [2020-07-10T12:35:28.034Z] Platform:      win32
[debug] [2020-07-10T12:35:28.035Z] Node Version:  v12.18.2
[debug] [2020-07-10T12:35:28.036Z] Time:          Fri Jul 10 2020 18:05:28 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] [2020-07-10T12:35:28.036Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2020-07-10T12:35:28.037Z] 
[info] i  Firebase optionally collects CLI usage and error reporting information to help improve our products. Data is collected in accordance with Google's privacy policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy) and is not used to identify you.
 
[info] i  To change your data collection preference at any time, run `firebase logout` and log in again. 
[info] 
[info] Visit this URL on this device to log in:
[info] https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=563584335869-fgrhgmd47bqnekij5i8b5pr03ho849e6.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email%20openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloudplatformprojects.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffirebase%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&response_type=code&state=3839&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A
[info] 
    [info] Waiting for authentication...
    [debug] [2020-07-10T12:57:25.170Z] Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
    [error] 
    [error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

On the new system, I am using the following software:

- node v12.18.2
- npm v6.14.5

On the old system, I was using the following software:

- node v10.16.3
- npm v6.12.0

I have also tried the following:

- executing `npm install -g firebase-tools@latest`
- executing all steps in a separate cmd running as admin.

Everything was working perfectly in my old workspace.

Comment: have you tried `firebase login` ?

Comment: Yes. I am getting this error when i tried firebase login

Comment: Try downgrading back to Node.js v10.

Comment: @ Daemon Beast, I had downgraded to 10. But still same Error.

Comment: Have you tried following the [link](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=563584335869-fgrhgmd47bqnekij5i8b5pr03ho849e6.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email%20openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloudplatformprojects.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffirebase%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&response_type=code&state=3839&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A) in the debug log?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try running `PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\System32` in a cmd, then run `firebase login`. Reference: [GitHub issue: Firebase login is not working](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1442#issuecomment-505970176).

Comment: Also, when pinging another user on Stack Overflow using **@**, there cannot be a space after the **@** or in the username otherwise it won't work. It should be **@DaemonBeast**.

Comment: @DaemonBeast Thanks, That works for me. I have added that in my path variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding **'C:\Windows\System32'** in my environment variable.